# German characters wrong in included php but OK on index.php

Tags: php, encoding

In my *index.php* I replaced

```html
<div class="site_content"> ... </div>
```

with

```php
<?php include ("site_content.php"); ?>
```

whilst all contents of the upper were copy&pasted into *site_content.php*.
The content now shows strange characters and the german encoding and charset (*UTF-8*) are not recognized any more. Before the change the encoding worked fine. The header of the index.php looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de">
    <head>
        <title>...some title.... </title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content=" ...some desc ...."/>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php include ("parts_index/site_content.php"); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: you should provide an example content of `site_content.php` as well.

Comment: Do both 'index.php' and 'site_content.php' containt a '<meta charset="UTF-8">' ?

Comment: <div id="site_content">  <!--begin site_content-->  
 <div class="content_item_text">
  <h1>Willkommen zur meine Seite</h1>
  <p>Wir freuen uns, Sie auf unseren Seiten begrüßen zu dürfen.tellen.</p>

 </div> <!--close content_item_text-->     
</div><!--close site_content-->

Comment: I tried to paste a head tag like I had in the index.php and also to embed the whole div above in a body tag (not correct from html point of view but at least FF 43.0.4 was parsing it right. I also tried to use the php header function as I found in forums. No success at all.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it.
The answer is very simple. The included php file was ANSI while my index.php was of course utf-8. When I converted the included file (site_content.php) to utf-8 no BOM it solved my problem! Thank you anyway for your time!
OZ